# ElasticSearch NEST custom word joiner Analyzer not returning the correct result

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I created an autocomplete filter with `ElasticSearch` using NEST API. I cant seem to get the word joiner to work.

So basically if I search for something like `Transhex` i also want to be able to return `Trans Hex`

My Index looks as follow...I think the WordDelimiter filter might be wrong.
Also, I followed the following article [Link](https://medium.com/@davedash/writing-a-space-ignoring-autocompleter-with-elasticsearch-6c3c28e3a974). They use the low-level API so it is possible that I am doing it completely wrong using the NEST API

```
var response = this.Client.CreateIndex(
                "company-index",
                index => index.Mappings(
                        ms => ms.Map<CompanyDocument>(m => m.Properties(p => p
                                .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyName).Analyzer("auto-complete")
                                .Fields(ff => ff.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword")))))))
                    .Settings(f => f.Analysis(
                        analysis => analysis
                            .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                                .Custom("auto-complete", a => a.Tokenizer("standard").Filters("lowercase", "word-joiner-filter", "auto-complete-filter")))
                            .TokenFilters(tokenFilter => tokenFilter
                                .WordDelimiter("word-joiner-filter", t => t.CatenateAll())
                                .EdgeNGram("auto-complete-filter", t => t.MinGram(3).MaxGram(30))))));
```

***UPDATE***
So I updated the Analyzer to look as follows, noticed that I updated the Analyzer from `standard` to `keyword`.

```
var response = this.Client.CreateIndex(
                this.indexName,
                index => index.Mappings(
                        ms => ms.Map<CompanyDocument>(m => m.Properties(p => p
                                .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyName).Analyzer("auto-complete")
                                .Fields(ff => ff.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword")))))))
                    .Settings(f => f.Analysis(
                        analysis => analysis
                            .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                                .Custom("auto-complete", a => a.Tokenizer("keyword").Filters("lowercase", "word-joiner-filter", "auto-complete-filter")))
                            .TokenFilters(tokenFilter => tokenFilter
                                .WordDelimiter("word-joiner-filter", t => t.CatenateAll())
                                .EdgeNGram("auto-complete-filter", t => t.MinGram(1).MaxGram(20))))));
```

The Results will look as follows

***Search Keyword*** : **perfect pools**

***Results***

1. perfect pools  ***-> This is the correct one at the top***
2. EXCLUSIVE POOLS
3. Perfect Painters

***Search Keyword*** : **perfectpools Or PerfectPools**

***Results***

1. Perfect Hideaways (Pty) Ltd ***-> this is the wrong one i would like to display perfect pools***
2. PERFORMANTA APAC PTY LTD
3. Perfect Laser Technologies (PTY) LTD

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you have used Standard tokenizer as opposed to Keyword tokenizer, and have Ngrams of size `3` to `30` as opposed to `1` to `20`. Can you show what results you're seeing returned, and why they're not correct?

Comment: @RussCam I Updated the question with results. Those are the actual results. just limiting to 3 otherwise it will get to big :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Keyword tokenizer. The standard tokenizer will split the word in 2 tokens, then apply the filters on them.

UPDATE:
I used a search like this one and seems ok.

```
var searchResult = EsClient.Search<CompanyDocument>(q => q
            .Index("test_index")
            .Type("companydocument")
            .TrackScores(true)
            .Query(qq =>
            {
                QueryContainer queryContainer = null;

                queryContainer = qq.QueryString(qs => qs.Fields(fs => fs.Field(f => f.CompanyName)).Query("perfectpools").DefaultOperator(Operator.And).Analyzer("auto-complete"));

                return queryContainer;
            })
             .Sort(sort => sort.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score))
             .Take(10)
            );
```

Comment: So basically leave everything as is and just replace 'standard' with 'keyword'

Comment: Yea i tried that did not work, check the update to the question. those are the actual results. So not getting what i am suppose to

Comment: do you have cerebro installed ?

Comment: No but i do have kibana installed

Comment: One question, why do you need the ngram stuff ? From what i see you are generating a lot of tokens.  could you also update the question adding the search code ? thanks.

Comment: PS : i tested and the :"perfectpools" is in the token list of that analyzer. now let's see the search stuff. maybe you are doing something bad and you get a better score for the : "Perfect Hideaways (Pty) Ltd".

Comment: I am using the ngrams because I am doing an auto-complete search. Ill see if I can add the search code.

Comment: check what i sent. should work. it works for me. But also depends on how you did the search. Also a good thing is to index the companyName in 2 diff fields. One for Ngram one for the joiner. then the search should be easier.